# How to get the assets controller in Play to detect new images?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

It seems that if you have play running in production mode, and any new images are added to the  `public/images` directory, the `Assets.at()` method does not detect these new images until Play has been stopped and restarted from the console.

Is there any way to force the Assets controller to refresh/recompile the list of assets while in production mode? Or do I have to write my own controller for serving up images? (If so, is there one already written to do this that I can reuse?)

Comment: Is this on a production system?  If so, then you probably should not be using the static asset controller for this purpose because your assets are changing dynamically.

Comment: @JamesWard Yeah, it is for production. And that pretty much sucks.

Comment: The Assets controller in Play pulls assets out of the classpath.  There are some good reasons for this.  As the answer below indicates, you can pretty easily write a new controller that will download files from the file system instead.

Comment: @JamesWard Its pretty lame to use classpath rather than file system when working with a website. What are those good reasons for using classpath?

Comment: In Play everything goes into jar files.  Even static assets.  This makes deployment and asset location lookup simple and consistent whether those assets are in a public directory or if they are compiled by an asset compiler.  It also makes it possible for libraries to include static assets which don't need to be moved around or configured.  WebJars takes advantage of this.

Comment: In general I think that using the filesystem to store dynamic images/data has become an anti-pattern because it uses the filesystem to store state which is not scalable.  Instead I'd recommend using S3, or Mongo's GridFS for dynamic file storage.  Then a simple controller can serve the binary assets out of those system.  Or in the case of S3 I put CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket and then have CloudFront serve requests for the images.

Comment: Yeah, because there is no easy way to provide fault-tolerance and scale beyond one instance when storing state on the filesystem.

Comment: Additional Info [Here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets)

Comment: @JamesWard Fair points, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write your own action for your uploaded pictures.

The `Assets` controller is a controller that serves **static** resources which are bundled within your application.

You can find a very simple (and low tech) example of an action for retrieving a picture [here](https://github.com/Ekito/mapMyCost-server/blob/master/app/controllers/Application.java#L164) (I think you'll get the idea).

Comment: You can start by checking the image extension, no ?